# C Wrapper for Mat::at - error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm writing a C wrapper for Mat::at and I'm doing one for all of the `<typename>`'s . This one for `Vec4s` won't run because I added the &. I had to do that on all my `Mat::at` C wrappers for `typenames` like `double`, `float`, `int` etc so I could use the wrapper to write to a matrix element as well as reading it.

In trying to add the & to the below wrapper I got the first error below the wrapper. I added a second & next to the first & in the below wrapper next to the function name only and got the second error below the wrapper...I thought why  was a c++11 thing, why my compiler wouldn't accept the second &,  so I added the -std=c++11 to my compiler argument(g++ on ubuntu trusty) and got 3rd error message...

The only stipulation is I have to be able to write to the matrix element with the `Mat:at` wrapper...Any help is much appreciated.

```
Vec4s* &cv_Mat_at_Vec4s1(Mat* self, int i, int j) {
  return &self->at<Vec4s>(i, j);
}
```

First Error - original

```
 error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
 ‘cv::Vec4s*& {aka cv::Vec<short int, 4>*&}’ from an rvalue of type 
 ‘cv::Vec<short int, 4>*’
 return &self->at<Vec4s>(i, j);
```

Second Error: no `-std=c++11`

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&&’ token
```

Third Error - added `-std=c++11`

```
 warning: returning reference to temporary
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return a pointer by value:

```
Vec4s* cv_Mat_at_Vec4s1(Mat* self, int i, int j) {
  return &self->at<Vec4s>(i, j);
}
```

If you're writing a C wrapper as you said, you can't return by reference anyway.

---

FYI, the first error was because you can't bind non-const references to temporaries (the temporary in your case being the result of taking the address of `self->at<Vec4s>(i, j);`).

The second error is because, you guessed it, rvalue references are C++11 feature.

The third error is because you were returning a reference to a temporary that goes out of scope after the function returns. Rvalue reference are still just references, they don't magically extend lifetime of objects.